# MYSQL - Timetable with value

Tags: mysql

maybe anybody has the power to help in building this query:

```
| datetimestamp       | value |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 1892  |
| 2020-01-01 01:00:00 | 1219  |
| 2020-01-01 02:00:00 | 1119  |
| ...                 | ...   |
| 2020-01-02 01:00:00 | 1619  |
| 2020-01-02 02:00:00 | 1419  |
| ...                 | ...   |
| 2020-01-02 01:00:00 | 1619  |
| 2020-01-02 02:00:00 | 1319  |
```

I wanna select for a month, the highest value of the hour to become this results

```
| 2020-01-02 01:00:00 | 1619 |
| 2020-01-02 02:00:00 | 1419 |
| ...                 | ...  |
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your datetimestamp column contain valid datetime values  you could use the date(), hour(), minute() function for retrive the part od datetime you need and  a subquery for max value based  on group by and join

```
select * from my_table m 
inner join  (
   select date(datetimestamp) my_date,  hour(datetimestamp) my_hour, minute(datetimestamp) my_minute, (max(datetimestamp)
   from my_table  
   group by date(datetimestamp) ,  hour(datetimestamp) , minute(datetimestamp)

   ) t on t.my_date = date(m.datetimestamp)
        and t.m_hour = hour(m.datetimestamp) 
            and t.my_minute =  minute(m.datetimestamp)
```